# How to check user ".profile" exist or not before running crontab in Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, cron, solaris-10

I am using **Solaris 10**.

I have another user apart from root say testuser, which is mounted in NAS file system
I have some script which need to be run as testuser. so I had added them to the crontab of testuser.

As long as NAS is up all the cronjobs are rqn properly, but when NAS goes down then cron itself crashed by giving **! could not obtain latest contract for PID 15621: No such process**
this error.

I search for this issue and came to know that because it's .profile file is not accessible due to which it is giving this error. So is **there any way by which we can check user specific .profile file exist or not before run any schedule job**

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that `cron` really crashes? If it does, the PID of the process will change as well as the time in `ps` output. If it does not crash, I'd look into the crontab of the affected user. By default, `cron` goes into user's home directory and executes the scheduled command using `/bin/sh` as the shell. This behavior can be changed but I'd analyze this first to understand the root cause of your problem.

Comment: @evolvah It seems to me that cron crash because same cron processes run fine when I configure it as a root user, I guess because at roo user .profile file exist so it is running fine. and another thing error which is coming is not related to script.........

Comment: Take guessing out of equation. Does the PID for cron itself change? If the PID changes, then cron crashes. If it does not change, cron does not crash and you need to look into your crontab.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to actively monitor the NAS share, and report an error (however errors are reported at your location) if it isn't. You can use tools like nfsstat to get statistics on the NAS share (assuming this NAS share is mounted via NFS). It seems a better solution than checking to see if it's working before running cron -- check to make sure the share is available, because if it isn't, attention is needed.

Cron doesn't depend on anything but time, so it will run regardless of whether or not the user's home directory is available. If the script that the cron job is running is local, then you could prepend a check to make sure the home directory is available before running, otherwise just exit with an error code.

If the script that cron is attempting to run is in the user's home directory, you're out of luck, because an error will occur in even trying to run the script to check for the existence. You will need to check the status of the NAS share before attempting to run the cron job, but the cron job will run regardless. See where I'm going?

Again, I would suggest monitoring the NAS and reporting when it is failing.

Comment: that is ok but when NAS is gone down it is creating some other problem as there are alots of mail are generated at /var/spool/clientqueue, due to which space issue are coming.

Comment: In that case, space capacity for /var should be monitored as well for the same reason. Catch it before it becomes a full filesystem. It's also possible to monitor sendmail (or postfix) for when too much mail is being deferred or rejected, or so I've heard.

Comment: I don't want such mail to be generate, so I redirect the standard error as well as output to /dev/null but still could not obtain latest pid kind of mail are generated and causing problem, do you have any idea how can I stop them to send such error msg ..................do you have any idea, is this is a bug in solaris

Comment: Check out [this link on Oracle's site](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2159958?start=0&tstart=0)